# Geometry Proof - Two Intersecting Circles Problem

Tags: geometry, circles, angle, tangent-line

This problem has been bugging me for the last week - anyone find the solution?!

[image: Diagram of circle.]

Given:

The points A,B and C are on circumference of the larger circle which has tangent $DE$ at $C$. $O$ is the circumcenter. The smaller circle passes through the center of the larger circle. 
Angle $BCE = 48^0$  between tangent $CE$ and chord $CB$.

Comment: It seems that the information you've given would hold true regardless of the length of $\overline{DE}$, so there wouldn't be a way to prove anything about how long it is. Is the question to prove that the point $C$ is not the center of the smaller circle?

Comment: BCE is 43° (as per text) or 48° (as per diagram)?

Comment: Maybe image says BCE=48?

Comment: There has to be more information other than $\angle BCE = 48$. This is because there exists a point $B$ on $\bigodot O$ where $\angle BCE = 48$ would exist if $\bigodot O$ and $\bigodot C$ share the same radius $CO$. If we knew that $OB|| DE$ then this would be simple, but as it stands it could actually be true.

Comment: If the second circle need to be smaller than the first, then it is true.  The center of the smaller circle can't be on the line DE.  If it was, then the radius of the small circle would be greater than the radius of the big circle ...  This explaination doesn't need the triangle or the value of BCE.

Comment: @AlainRemillard, if you would like to turn your comment into an answer, I'll delete mine, which essentially says the same thing.  (I didn't read the comments carefully before posting it.)

Comment: @BarryCipra, I decided to only comment since I tought the question was incomplete.  Your answer is fine and I'm glad I'm not the only one who thought of it.

Answer (score 2):

Any circle whose center lies along the line $DE$ (so that the line $DE$ acts as a diameter) and which passes through the center $O$ of the "larger" circle necessarily has radius *at least as large* as the "larger" circle.  So if the circle in question is indeed *smaller* than the circle centered at $O$ with the line $DE$ tangent at $C$, its center cannot lie along the line $DE$, and hence $DE$ cannot be a diameter of it.

Note, this has *nothing* at all to do with the triangle $\triangle ABC$ or the measure of the angle $\angle BCE$.  All that information is a red herring.

Remark:  I just noticed, this answer essentially duplicates a remark made by Alain Remillard below the OP.

Answer (score 0):

If fixing positions of $A,B,C$ is required, note that angle $A$ in the alternate segment equals $48^0$ as angle between chord/tangent and so vertex $A$ can be placed *anywhere* on the large arc segment $CB.$
I have drawn several circles which are arbitrarily placed. Why should an arbitrary circle cut a given tangent line specifically along its diameter? It need not even cut at all.

To develop thought clarity one has to put all that is known on one side and all that is to be solved for, on the other. Then connect them up.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If the diameter of the circle-to-be-constructed lies on DE, then we have the following two cases:-

(1) C is its center with CO as its radius --- Then, the green circle is formed with its size the same as the red one but NOT larger.

(2) $C’$ (an arbitrary point on DE other than C) is its center with $C’O$ as its radius --- Then, the purple circle is formed with its size larger than the green one because **$C’O$ is the hypotenuse of $\triangle COC’$**.

The conclusion is:-

“any circle drawn through O with diameter lying on DE must be smaller than (and at most equal to) circle $ABC$”.

Comment: $\angle BCE$ is 48 not $\angle BAC$

Comment: @Sentinel135 They are the same by "angles in alternate segment".

Comment: Shouldn't your conclusion be that the circle through $O$ with diameter on $DE$ must be *larger* than (*or at least* equal to) the other circle???

Comment: @BarryCipra I guess the meanings of both are more or less the same. It is just a matter of how to infer the target requirement --- "DE is NOT a diameter (of any circle smaller than ABC)".  The question statement itself is not that properly asked.

Answer (score 0):

For us to define a circle such that one is smaller than the other will require the distance and betweenness axioms. If you don't have those available to you than I suggest doing something different. I will continue with those axioms assumed.

Let $\bigodot (O,r)$ and $\bigodot (P,s)$ such that $\bigodot (O,r)$ is the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$ with radius $r$, and $\bigodot (P,s)$ is the smaller circle who's radius is $s$, and center is $P$ and intersects at $O$. Note that this implies $r>s$.

---

Suppose $DE$ is the diameter of $\bigodot (P,s)$. This implies that there is a $P$ on $DE$ such that $P$ bisects $DE$. Construct line $PO$. As $r > s$ there exists a point $P^\prime$ such that $P^\prime O\cong CO = r$. Construct line $P^\prime C$. Note  $P^\prime O\cong CO$ implies $\triangle COP^\prime$ is isosceles. By pons asinorum $\angle CP^\prime O \cong \angle P^\prime CO$. Since $$\angle P^\prime CO = \angle P^\prime CP+\angle PCO=\angle P^\prime CP+ 90^o,$$ this implies that,
$$\begin {array}{ccc}   
\angle CP^\prime O+ \angle P^\prime CO+\angle COP^\prime &=& 2\angle P^\prime CO+\angle COP^\prime \\
&=& 2(90^o)+2\angle P^\prime CP+\angle COP^\prime \\
&>& 180^o
\end{array}$$
a contradiction.